# List all existing filetypes (including sub-directories) using DOS Batch Command

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a drive with numerous directories and sub-directories (several levels deep).  I would like to create a DOS batch file (for Win8/2012+) that will find all existing filetypes on the drive and list them.

I'm having trouble creating such a batch command.  If anyone could help me out, I would very much appreciate it.

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /r %%a in (*) do (
    if "%%~xa" neq "" if not defined %%~xa (
        set "%%~xa=."
        echo %%~xa
    ) 
)
endlocal
```

Comment: Should this not fail with extensions that contain an equal sign?

Comment: @MCND ahmm it will fail. This didnt came to me but anyway its a rare case

Comment: Thank you very much, npocmaka.  It's perfect!  I was stuck on the %%~xa parameter as I didn't know how to look for just extensions.  Many thanks.